# Nhibernate - remove and re-add the same item in a collection - does nhibernate delete and readd in the database?

Tags: nhibernate

If I have a collection on an entity and I remove an item from the collection and then readd it, all before calling repository.update(entity), will nhibernate know what I did and delete and readd the item, or will it just see there was no material change and do nothing?

Comment: I guess it depends whether the ID of the deleted object had the same as the one you added. When the ID remains the same I think nHibernate will not change anything in the database.

Comment: Olando...apparently it replays the actions I took. The first thing it did was delete all the items and then it re-added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Confirmed! Yes it does!**

I tried it while running sql profiler, and it will play out what you do to your objects. I guess that's the only safe way to go.